# Existence of an element

Tags: selenium, java

I have seen a couple of ways to test if an element exists. One way:

```
private boolean existsElement(String id) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And another way:

```
Boolean isPresent = driver.findElements(By.yourLocator).size() > 0
```

but adding an exception to test something isn't good practice and using the size method will take too long if you have an implicit wait.

Are there any other efficient ways to test for existence? If not, which of the two will be the preferred way to do it?

Comment: This is not the first time a question like this is asked. I have a hard time to understand in what cases you want to continue if an element does not exists, maybe you can give more context? I think when you write a test you should know the state and either the element exists or it doesnt. If you want to wait until an element does not exists anymore there is also a way for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646031/selenium-wait-until-element-is-not-visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FDM has the right idea.  Since his example is C#, I thought I'd provide a Java equivalent:

```
/*
 * Returns true if the at least one element is found.
 * If none are found, a list of size 0 is found.
 */
public boolean doesElementExist(String id) {
    return driver.findElements(By.id(id)).size() != 0;
}
```

This example is very basic and doesn't try waiting for an element.  If you wanted to allow the method to have a grace period to let the element appear, you could do something like:

```
/*
 * Wait up to 5 seconds for an element to become present.  Returns true if the element becomes present 
 * within the time limit, otherwise false.
 */
public boolean waitAndCheckPresence(String id) {
    int secondsToWait = 5;

    try {
        new WebDriverWait(driver, secondsToWait).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id(id)));
        return true;
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Typically, you should be able to avoid setting webdriver's implicit wait to be a large number because it can make certain operations like finding elements slow down your test.

Using `WebDriverWait` with the many `ExpectedConditions` options to create on call reactive delays is a better way to go about it so you aren't globally affecting your entire test.  Always minimize the scope that your code affects.

If you do need to change your implicit wait, you can do it with this code `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);` to make it near instant.  But remember to change it back after otherwise you will introduce potential undefined behavior into your test.

Comment: Will isDisplayed() method be a good alternative?

Comment: For this, not exactly.  isDisplayed checks the the css display attribute on the element.  If the element is 'display: none' then it will return false.  isDisplayed has nothing to do with presence, and if the element is not found it will throw a NoSuchElementException.  Take into consideration that the element must exist before you can get the reference to call isDisplayed() on as well :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official documentation](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElement-org.openqa.selenium.By-), `findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use findElements(By) and assert zero length response instead`.

It's easy to put that in a wrapper method, and temporarily reduce the implicit waiting time to a very low number. An example in C#, kind of:

```
    public static bool isElementPresent(IWebDriver d, By locator)
    {
        d.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        bool isPresent = driver.findElements(locator).size() > 0;
        d.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(defaultTimeVariable);
        return isPresent;
    }
```